# href geo: fallback for non-mobile browsers?

Tags: href, geo, fallback

I want to use  to open clients possible mobile navigation software, but how can i fallback to a normal URL if geo isn't assoicated with any program on the device?

E.g. in firefox on PC i get this message;
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (geo) isn't associated with any program.